# Is "swung onto his back" correct?

Tags: word-usage

> The terrorist fumbles for his rifle, which has **swung onto his back**. But before he can **grab it**, a few of the hostages charge at him.

(The rifle is on a sling)

Is "swung onto his back" correct?

Also, is "grab it" okay?

Comment: No, the sling is actually a strap. When you put our arm **through** the sling attached at either end of a rifle, you grab that strap, your elbow goes through the loop and rifle moves to your back. But the passive "swung onto this back** does not work.

Comment: You could say **which is slung over his back**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine. We often attribute involuntary actions to objects they're performed upon, even if the rifle cannot decide to swing by itself:

> My earbuds have tangled themselves into a knot.

Of course, I tangled the earbuds by mishandling them, but since it wasn't something I did willingly, I put the blame on the earbuds themselves. So in this case the terrorist has moved in a way that caused the rifle to perform a swinging motion and end up on his back.

As for *grab it* - it's fine, I don't see any problem, either actual or potential.

Comment: I would never say, *My earbuds have tangled themselves into a knot.* Instead I would say, *My earbuds have become tangled/knotted.*